# Selenium: alert when getting page source

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am seeing probably strange behavior of Selenium when trying to get page source using the following code:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=ff_profile, firefox_options=ff_options)
driver.get(url)
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "%s[%s='%s']" % (SectionTag, SectionAttrName, SectionAttrValue))))
    time.sleep(5)
    except TimeoutException as ex:
        driver.close()
    else:
        pageSource = driver.page_source
        try:
            driver.switch_to_alert().dismiss()
        except NoAlertPresentException:
            print ("no alert")
        driver.close()
```

That leads to an error:

```
    pageSource = driver.page_source
  File "/home/ura/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 532, in page_source
    return self.execute(Command.GET_PAGE_SOURCE)['value']
  File "/home/ura/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/ura/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: None
Message:
```

I have tried to add alert handling but it didn't help.

Any ideas please?

Comment: WebDriver is blocked by opened alert , so it should be closed before you can get page source.Just try to put alert handling code *before* `pageSource = driver.page_source` line

Comment: Did you figure this problem out? I'm having the same issue....